# Standard in Thymeleaf for Date, Time, Number format

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there a possibility in Thymeleaf to define the standard format for:

- Date
- Time
- DateTime
- Number

Something which I can do in the config? E.g. for Date I would like have "dd.MM.yyyy" etc.
I know I can use than in the HTML code something, like:

```
${#dates.formatISO(standardDate)}
```

But I would like to have a **Standard format** for LocalDate, LocalTime, Number...
If I use a function in the HTML, it should use for sure than this config.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as an aside, you should try to avoid using the old, problematic Java [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) class - and the related Thymeleaf [`#dates`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates) expression utility object. Instead, use the modern [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes - and the related Thymeleaf [`#temporals`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#temporals-java.time) expression utility.